# TCP communication on Windows Azure

Tags: sockets, tcp, azure, azure-configuration

Is it possible to create a service on Azure that handles a socket (ip:port) to get raw tcp data from clients and send some data back to them?

I am a little bit confused in this topic, somewhere I read it is possible, other pleces say it is impossible.

Note, my devices I want to communicate with can send data via tcp **to a given IP address, it is not possible to set server as a DNS name** in that devices. So, it is also an important question if Azure platform providers can provide also IP or just DNS names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tom, with any type of Windows Azure role, you can define tcp endpoints and assign a specific port to each endpoint. You can then start a ServiceHost (or anything, for that matter) that listens on that tcp endpoint. If you scale to multiple instances, each of your instances would listen on that endpoint for new connections, and the Windows Azure load balancer would take care of sending requests across your instances.

You can certainly connect via IP address instead of DNS name, but the IP address is subject to change if you delete and redeploy your app.

**EDIT 12/14/2012** - Last October, there was [announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/10/19/announcing-improved-in-place-updates.aspx) about improved in-place updates. You'll see that many types of changes may now be made to the deployment without the assigned IP address changing.

Comment: Thx very much. Lack of fox IP is bad news for me, hopefully there would be that feature in the future.

Comment: I wrote a blog about how to do something like that with a WCF service a while ago http://lab.studiopesec.com/azure-applications-101-part-ii/ . Maybe it can shed some light: when you create your tcp host, make sure you look at the internalendpoint name. And make sure you use an internal endpoint because those are free :)

Comment: Internal endpoints won't help at all when hosting a service for the outside world to consume (and they're not free - you still have to host the instances). You'll need an Input Endpoint for external visibility. Free inbound data to your service as well.